# Difference between "date limite" and "délai"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Both [date limite](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/date-limite) and [délai](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/d%C3%A9lai) can be used to mean *deadline*. Notwithstanding the fact that *délai* has other meanings, are the two words complete synonyms in the sense of *deadline*? Or are there cases where we would use one but not the other?

Comment: If I have until 20/01/2017 to do something, **20/01/2017** is my "date limite" and **10 days** is my "délai". There may be cases where "délai" is used in a same way as "date limite", I don't know.

Comment: Note that *délai* and "delay" are false friends. A delay is *un retard*, and by the way "retard" (as slang) is also a false friend…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two words are not synonyms. *Date limite* refers to a point on the time line and *délai* to a period of time.

> Quel est la date limite pour rendre ce travail ?
>   Tu dois avoir fini pour vendredi soir/ la fin de la semaine.

> Quel est le délai pour faire ce travail ?
>   Tu as dix jours.

It seems to me that *date limite* is closer to "deadline" than to *délai*, although *date limite* does not always translated as "deadline". For example, *date limite de vente* is "sell by date".

I can't think of an instance where I'd translate *délai* a "deadline".

- *Quel est le délai pour rendre ce travail* ? → How long have I got to hand in this work?
- *Le délai de livraison est de  3  jours*. → Allow 3 days for delivery.
- *Le délai d'attente moyen est d'au moins huit jours*. → The average waiting time is at least a week.

Sometimes *délai* is translated as "delay", but I can only think of one instance.
*Puis-je avoir un délai pour finir ce travail ?*  →
Can I have a delay to finish that work?

Comment: Date limite can I think be translated to "due date" or "target date"

Answer (score 1):

It's not really the same meaning : "date limite" is a milestone, "délai" is a duration. But you can say : "Je t'accorde un délai jusqu'à cette date limite".

Answer (score 0):

"Data limite" would be deadline/milestone, whereas "delai" is more like leadtime/delay, as in "delay line" in electronics, precisely. For sure, "delai" refers to a duration, whereas "date limite" refers to a point in time.